# MySQL Query to Determine if Member is a Friend of a Friend to another Member

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores friends as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `to_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

INSERT INTO `friends` (`id`, `to_id`, `from_id`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 2, 3, 'pending', '2013-08-10 00:00:00', '2013-08-10 00:00:00'),
(2, 1, 3, 'approved', '2013-08-11 00:00:00', '2013-08-11 00:00:00'),
(3, 2, 1, 'approved', '2013-08-15 20:51:20', '2013-08-15 20:51:20');
```

I want to be able to determine if a member (we'll call the viewer) is a friend-of-a-friend to another member (the profile they are viewing). I need this information to determine if the viewer is allowed to view the profile. Let's say I (id of 2) am viewing the profile with id of 3. The query below is what I have so far.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM profiles 
LEFT JOIN friends ON (profiles.id = friends.to_id OR profiles.id = friends.from_id) 
WHERE (friends.to_id = 2) OR (friends.from_id = 2)
AND profiles.id IN (
    SELECT profiles.id 
    FROM profiles 
    LEFT JOIN friends ON (profiles.id = friends.to_id OR profiles.id = friends.from_id)
    WHERE (friends.to_id = 3) OR (friends.from_id = 3)
    GROUP BY profiles.id
)
AND friends.status = 'approved';
```

When I run this in PHPMyAdmin I get 4, but shouldn't I get 1 because there is 1 other member that we are both friends with? Once I run this in my model I am then making sure that if there are more than 0 rows returned then I am okay to view the profile. Can anybody help tweak this so that it runs properly? I am kind of lost at this point. Thanks in advance.

I was able to figure it out and here is the working query below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
                FROM profiles 
                WHERE profiles.id IN (
                    SELECT profiles.id 
                    FROM profiles
                    LEFT JOIN friends ON (friends.to_id = profiles.id OR friends.from_id = profiles.id)
                    WHERE (friends.to_id = 1 OR friends.from_id = 1)
                    AND profiles.id != 1
                )
                AND profiles.id IN (
                    SELECT profiles.id 
                    FROM profiles 
                    LEFT JOIN friends ON (friends.to_id = profiles.id OR friends.from_id = profiles.id)
                    WHERE (friends.to_id = 3 OR friends.from_id = 3)
                    AND profiles.id != 3
                )
```

Comment: Please add example data, expected output and where you are stuck.

Comment: Query Facebook's API. :)

Comment: This is not for a Facebook app. This is for a website that I am developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a moment, don't think of it as of a table.

In order to qualify for a mutual friend, a user must be in my circle AND other user's circle. Intersection of sets.

So you have:

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id IN (SELECT viewers friends IDs) AND id IN (SELECT the viewed users friends IDS);
```

Write sub-queries is left as an exercise ;)

Comment: This explanation was just what I needed. Thanks, and I edited my original post with the query I am using.